# Web Audio API: how can I detect speech and record until silence, with or without a Push-To-Talk button

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder, voice-detection

I'm running succesfully a client web page that act as a voice message sender, using `MediaRecorder` APIs:

- when the user press any key, start an audio recording,
- when the key is released, the audio recording is sent, via soketio, to a server for further processing.

This is a sort of **PTT (Push To Talk)** user experience, where the user has just to press a key (push) to activate the voice recording. And afterward he must release the key to stop the recording, triggering the message send to the server.

Here a javascript code chunk I used:

```js
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(stream => {

          const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
          var audioChunks = []

          //
          // start and stop recording:
          // keyboard (any key) events
          //
          document
            .addEventListener('keydown', () => mediaRecorder.start())

          document
            .addEventListener('keyup', () => mediaRecorder.stop())

          //
          // add data chunk to mediarecorder
          //
          mediaRecorder
            .addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
              audioChunks.push(event.data)
            })

          //
          // mediarecorder event stop
          // trigger socketio audio message emission.
          //
          mediaRecorder
            .addEventListener('stop', () => {
               socket.emit('audioMessage', audioChunks)
              audioChunks = []
            })

        })
```

---

Now, What I want is to activate/deactivate the audio(speech) recording not only from a web page button/key/touch, but from an **external hardware microphone (with a Push-To-Talk button)**. More precisely, I want to interface an industrial headset with PTT button on the ear dome, see the photo:

[image: industrial headset with PTT button on the ear dome]

BTW, the `PTT` button is just a physical button that act as short-circuit toggle switch, as in the photo, just as an example:
[image: Push To Talk button circuit]

- By default the microphone is grounded and input signal == 0
- When the `PTT` button is pressed, the micro is activated and input signal != 0.

Now my question is: how  can I use Web Audio API to possibly detect when the PTT button is pressed (so audio signal is > 0) to do a `mediaRecorder.start()` ?

reading [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio#access_the_raw_data_from_the_microphone):  I guess I have to use the stream returned by `mediaDevices.getUserMedia` and create an `AudioContext()` processor:

```js
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
      .then(handleSuccess);

  const handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    const context = new AudioContext();
    const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    const processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);

    source.connect(processor);
    processor.connect(context.destination);

    processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
      // Do something with the data, 
      console.log(e.inputBuffer);
    };
  };
```

But what the `processor.onaudioprocess` function must do to start (volume > DELTA) and stop (volume < DELTA) the MediaRecorder?

I guess the volume detection could be useful for two situation:

- With `PTT` button, where the user explicitly decide the duration of the speech, pressing and releasing the button
- Without the `PTT` button, in this case the voice message is created with the so called `VOX` mode (continous audio processing)

Any idea?

Comment: web audio api has an event loop ... audio buffer is populated inside this loop ... to identify silence just probe this buffer and after X time period of RMS amplitude < Y declare silence

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515978/html-audio-recording-until-silence

Comment: thx @ScottStensland following your suggestion, I made:   https://github.com/solyarisoftware/WeBAD

Answer (score 3):

I answer to my question just to share a solution I found.

The @cwilso old project: [volume-meter](https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter) seems to be the precise implementation of what @scott-stensland stated in comment above. See the demo: https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/volume-meter/

UPDATE

BTW, using @cwilso project and @scott-stensland suggestion, I implemented a WeBAD opensource project to solve also my original question:

https://github.com/solyarisoftware/WeBAD