# Is there a way I can remove the silence from start and end of a .wav file?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

I am using react-ffmpeg to remove the silence from start and end of an audio but it seems to not work, Can you recommend a package or some code for removing silence from and audio? Here is my code.

```
   const onFileChange = async (e) => {


const file = e.target.files[0];
await FFMPEG.process(
  file,
  '-af silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=-50dB,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=-50dB,areverse',
  function (e) {
    const audio = e.result;
    console.log(audio);
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(audio)

    //URL for downloading
    setUrl(objectURL)
    console.log("url",objectURL)
  }
);
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013299/trim-silence-in-front-end-with-web-audio-api-or-anything-else

Comment: There is an ffmpeg filter 'silenceremove' but I have no idea if it's feasible to use it with react-ffmpeg.

Comment: I have tried the silenceremove on my code but it seems to not work. The output file size is 0.